# How to create numpy array with values in specific range?

Tags: python, numpy, range

How can I create a numpy array which has values in  a specific range. For instance only from 2 to 10! I know that  `np.arrange(10)` will create an array with 10 values from 0 to 9 but not sure how to indicate that I want it to have values in a specific range. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: `np.arange(2, 11)`

Comment: `np.arange(2, 11)` - see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: ultimately always read the docs :)

Answer (score 3):

As others and the documentation says

```
np.arange(2,11)
```

Here is a working example https://repl.it/@Sudakatux/simplenumpy

Here are the docs:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html